# pip install custom git repository, changes are not applied

Tags: python, pip

In my python project I have an intern git repository as a dependency. here is the line in the requirements.txt

```
git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrepo.git@my-branch
```

It worked well until now. Every time I push something to *my-branch* and re-call the installation whith :

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

the changes are not appearing in the folders of my Python dependency.
I tried the options **--no-cache-dir**, **--upgrade**, nothing seems to fix this.

I can provide further informations if needed, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out by myelf
It appears that I have to add my new files in the *package_data* inside the **setup.py** file of myrepo.git

**my_repo/setup.py**

```
setup(
    name='my_repo',
    ...
    package_data={
        'my_repo': [
            'my_new_folder/*',
             ...
    ]
)
```